# Markdown plugin in ckeditor does not work

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, markdown

I successfully installed ckeditor within a symfony project and also activated the markdown plugin by:

```
$builder->add('content', CKEditorType::class, array(
            'config' => array(
                'extraPlugins' => 'markdown',
            ),
            'plugins' => array(
                'wordcount' => array(
                    'path'     => '/bundles/ivoryckeditor/plugins/markdown/',
                    'filename' => 'plugin.js',
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

It works so far, the markdown button appears in the textarea panel. But when I click the button, button and textfield become grey and I get this error in console:

> InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character (line 74)

edit: I again also tried to create a ckeditor with markdown plugin using the builder on ckeditor.com and replaced the public folder of the bundle with the downloaded editor, but still the markdown button throws the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the plugin version on ckeditor.com is buggy and never worked. The newest version from https://github.com/hectorguo/CKEditor-Markdown-Plugin works.

Its even necessary, to have the [maximize plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/maximize) onboard, otherwise you cant get back from markdown view to normal view (you will see an error in console, that the command maximize is not found). Currently, this dependence is not mentioned in the markdown plugin.